# How do I prove the Poincare inequality for $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ be bounded connected, open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with $C^1$ boundary. Let $q=\frac{pn}{n-p}$. Prove the following Poincare inequality for $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$:

$$\|u- (u)_U\|_{L^q(U)}\leq C \|Du\|_{L^p(U)}.$$

My idea: I read the Poincare inequality proof in Evan's book, that said $\|u- (u)_U\|_{L^p(U)}\leq C \|Du\|_{L^p(U)}$ for each function $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$.

I used the general embedding theorem, according to this embedding if $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$, then $u \in L^q(U)$ under some conditions.

Now I am little confuse to connect these two result to make conclusion.

Can anyone suggest, how do I connect both result to solve the given inequality?

Comment: If the typographical difference between $||u||$ and $\|u\|$ is not conspicuous to you, look at this difference: $$ \begin{align} & \|u\|\|v\| \\ & ||u|| ||v|| \end{align}$$ The former is coded as `\|u\|\|v\|` and the latter as `||u|| ||v||`. The former usage is standard. (Also, I changed one line of your question from inline to display.) $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

You know $W^{1,p} \hookrightarrow L^q$, i.e., $\|u\|_{L^q} \leq \tilde C  \|u\|_{W^{1,p}}=\tilde C (\|u\|_{L^p}^p+\|Du\|_{L^p}^p)^{1/p}$. Hence we conclude

$$\begin{aligned}\|u-(u)_U\|_{L^q} &\leq \tilde C(\|u-(u)_U\|_{L^p}^p+\|Du\|_{L^p}^p)^{1/p} \\ &\leq \tilde C(C^p\|Du\|_{L^p}^p+\|Du\|_{L^p}^p)^{1/p} \\ &=\tilde C (C^p+1)^{1/p} \|Du\|_{L^p}.  \end{aligned}$$

Comment: I think in the first line, $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}=\|u\|_{L^{p}}+\|Du\|_{L^{p}}$.

Comment: It depends how you define the Sobolev norm. In fact, they are equivalent.

Comment: In the second line, when you replace $u$ with $u-(u)_U$. How do we say $\|D(u-(u)_U\| \leq \|Du\|$?

Comment: @User124356 The derivative of the mean is zero since the mean is a constant value.

Comment: @Fritz Let $U$ bounded, and $p^*= \frac{np}{n-p}$ and $n>p$, then

$W^{1,p}(U) \subset L^{p^{*}}(U)$
This inclusion is not compact. Can you tell me why?